# Best time for charging battery

Tags: battery

My laptop has 2 batteries. The laptop uses one of them until 5% and then starts using another one. Isn't this percentage bad and harmful for first battery?

Details:

Vendor: LGC

Model: 45N1735

Technology: Lithium Ion

Laptop: Thinkpad t440

Comment: As for why, I would guess that it first tries to use the swappable battery as much as possible, and then the internal battery. The potential reduction in lifespan is probably worth the benefit of maximizing total battery life when you have a spare available. It might even be possible to configure this behavior with a system utility provided by the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but only if it's left on 5% for a long time (half a week or so)

Comment: No this isn't harmful. I would be lead to believe this is actually desired as you'd wear down one battery heavier, which would lead to less e-waste. May also be a technical limitation there somewhere where you couldn't drain from both at once. Hope this helps.